# Git clone repo in Dockerfile lags

Tags: git, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to clone a private repo hosted by bitbucket to a docker container. My Dockerfile is as follow

```
RUN git clone git@deploy:<blabla>.git /src/<blabla>
WORKDIR /src/<blabla>
RUN cd /src/<blabla>
RUN git pull --all --tags
RUN git checkout v1.1.2
RUN pip install .
```

The problem I have: I am said that the tag `v1.1.2` does not exist. To confirm that, I change the Dockerfile with

```
RUN git clone git@deploy:<blabla>.git /src/<blabla>
WORKDIR /src/<blabla>
RUN cd /src/<blabla>
RUN git pull --all --tags
RUN git branch
RUN git tag
RUN git checkout v1.1.2
RUN pip install .
```

where I can see that the last created branch and the last tag are now cloned indeed. The workaround I found is to make a double pull

```
RUN git clone git@deploy:<blabla>.git /src/<blabla>
WORKDIR /src/<blabla>
RUN cd /src/<blabla>
RUN git pull --all --tags
RUN git pull --all --tags
RUN git checkout v1.1.2
RUN pip install .
```

and now everything works great.

Comment: git clone --mirror <url> clones all branches and tags, than you can  git checkout v1.1.2

Comment: Does the same happen with `docker build --no-cache`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RUN git clone -b 'v1.1.2' --single-branch --depth 1 git@deploy:<blabla>.git /src/<blabla> \
   && cd /src/<blabla> \
   && pip install .

WORKDIR /src/<blabla>
```

Git clone can directly fetch the tag, and adding `--single-branch` and `--depth` avoid to clone the whole repository history to the container.

It's a bit more compact and avoids extra layers. You can still break it into multiple lines of you want.